# contentEditable cursor's parent element

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable, cursor-position

I have a contentEditable HTML element. I would like to get the cursor's parent element. For example, if the cursor is inside a table cell, I would like to display some controls for editing the table. Is this possible? Or am I going to track all key and mousepresses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/vv9gD/) using [parentNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.parentNode):

```
document.getElementById('editable').onclick = function () {
 alert(this.parentNode.id);   
}
```

Comment: If you have nested tags in your editable element, you'll have to use `event.target.parentNode.id`: http://jsfiddle.net/vv9gD/1/

Comment: What if they're adjusting the cursor with keypresses? How do I get the parentNode from the selection range?

Comment: @Azmisov, event.target would work like a champ for key presses

Comment: @ComFreek, thank you. you are absolutely correct. Actually, it will be best to do event.target from the beginning. I'll update my answer

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out. Here is the final code: http://jsfiddle.net/vv9gD/5/